# How do I re-build django's password hashing in nim?

Tags: encryption, passwords, nim-lang

I'm rewriting my webapplication from Python (Django) to Nim (Prologue).
I want to keep using Django's database that it has provided me with thus far, but I'm struggling how to re-build the way Django encrypts the password.
That is, according to [Django's own documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/):

> By default, Django uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash

I found the [nimcrypto](https://github.com/cheatfate/nimcrypto) library as a starting point, but given my lack of cryptographic knowledge a lot of the terminology in there and how to use the given procs goes completely over my head. How can I rebuild the Django encryption using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning:** As has been pointed out to me, it might be a better idea to use a [nim-wrapper](https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/nim-libsodium) of [libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org/) for this, as it is the more established library. How you would do that is beyond me though, as libsodium has no obvious "pbkdf2" functions. However, using openssl directly as in the latter 2 approaches should also be perfectly valid.

##### 1) In pure nim with nimcrypto

After researching this topic for a fair bit and going over the code in the django repo and the nimcrypto lib, I was able to reproduce the hashes I have in my database. The key here is, that nimcrypto has a pbkdf2 proc in a module of the same name, that you need to pass an `HMAC` type, which contains the sha256 algorithm as well as your server's secret key. You also need to be aware that the hashes stored in your database as strings will have the number of iterations and salt appended to them. They'll also be base64 encoded versions of the hash.

```
import nimcrypto
import nimcrypto/pbkdf2
import base64

var hctx: HMAC[sha256]
let serverSecretKey = "YourServersSecretKeyInDjangoFromSettings"
hctx.init(serverSecretKey)

let password = "thePasswordToHash"
let salt = "asalt" #<-- You have to get this one from the passwords entry in your database
var output: array[32, byte] # <-- 256 bits stored in 32 bytes
let iterations = 180000 # <-- You have to get this one from the passwords entry in your database

discard pbkdf2(hctx, password, salt, iterations, output) #The output of pbkdf2 is irrelevant, you care of the hash in the `output` byte array aka the digest

let newHash = encode(output) # This turns the byte.array into a base64 encoded string. That string should be identical to the hash-string you have in your database.
```

Edit:

##### 2) In nim and python with openssl

I have since learned of the existence of [nimpy](https://github.com/yglukhov/nimpy), an incredible project for importing nim into python and vice versa. Using it, we can recreate the [method django uses for hashing.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8d160f154f0240a423e83ffe0690e472f837373c/django/utils/crypto.py#L70)

```
import nimpy

proc python_calculate_SHA256_pbkdf2_hash(password: string, salt: string, iterations: int, secretKey: string): string {.gcsafe.} =
    let hashlib = pyImport("hashlib")
    let pyBase64 = pyImport("base64")
    let djangoEncodingUtils = pyImport("django.utils.encoding")

    let password = djangoEncodingUtils.force_bytes(password)
    let salt = djangoEncodingUtils.force_bytes(salt)
    let hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", password, salt, iterations)
    let string_hash = pyBase64.b64encode(hash).decode("ascii").strip()
    return $string_hash
```

This will be significantly (at least 2x) faster, mostly because pythons "hashlib" is wrapping an incredibly efficient C library.

##### 3) In pure nim with a direct import of openssl

2nd Edit:

Thanks to hotdog and xflywind there now is a refactored version of the python code that just directly does the calls to openssl. It is slightly faster than the python version according to the haphazard benchmarks that were run of the python version against the pure nim version:

```
from std/openssl import EVP_MD, DLLUtilName, DLLSSLName
import std/[strformat, base64]

proc PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(
  pass: cstring,
  passLen: cint,
  salt: cstring,
  saltLen: cint,
  iter: cint,
  digest: EVP_MD,
  keylen: cint,
  output: cstring
): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLSSLName, importc: "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC".}

proc EVP_MD_size_fixed*(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_MD_get_size".}
proc EVP_sha256_fixed*(): EVP_MD {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_sha256".}

proc opensslCalculateSHA256Pbkdf2Hash(password: string, salt: string, iterations: int): string {.gcsafe.} =
  let hasTooManyIterations = iterations > cint.high
  if hasTooManyIterations: 
    raise newException(ValueError, fmt"You can not have more iterations than a c integer can carry. Choose a number below {cint.high}")

  let digest: EVP_MD = EVP_sha256_fixed()
  let hashLength: cint = EVP_MD_size_fixed(digest)
  let output = newString(hashLength)
  let outputStartingpoint: cstring = cast[cstring](output[0].unsafeAddr)

  let hashOperationReturnCode = PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(
      password.cstring,
      -1,
      salt.cstring,
      len(salt).cint,
      iterations.cint,
      digest,
      hashLength,
      outputStartingpoint
    )

  let wasHashSuccessful = hashOperationReturnCode == 1
  doAssert wasHashSuccessful

  result = encode(output)
```

3rd edit:

##### 4) Variation of 3) compatible with openssl 3

With openssl 3 the `EVP_MD_size` function got renamed to `EVP_MD_get_size`. That and a general minor refactor made me want to post this updated version of 3).

```
from std/openssl import EVP_MD, DLLUtilName, DLLSSLName
import std/[strformat, base64]

proc PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(
  pass: cstring,
  passLen: cint,
  salt: cstring,
  saltLen: cint,
  iter: cint,
  digest: EVP_MD,
  keylen: cint,
  output: cstring
): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLSSLName, importc: "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC".}

proc EVP_MD_size_fixed*(md: EVP_MD): cint {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_MD_get_size".}
proc EVP_sha256_fixed*(): EVP_MD {.cdecl, dynlib: DLLUtilName, importc: "EVP_sha256".}

proc opensslCalculateSHA256Pbkdf2Hash(password: string, salt: string, iterations: int): string {.gcsafe.} =
  let hasTooManyIterations = iterations > cint.high
  if hasTooManyIterations: 
    raise newException(ValueError, fmt"You can not have more iterations than a c integer can carry. Choose a number below {cint.high}")

  let digest: EVP_MD = EVP_sha256_fixed()
  let hashLength: cint = EVP_MD_size_fixed(digest)
  let output = newString(hashLength)
  let outputStartingpoint: cstring = cast[cstring](output[0].unsafeAddr)

  let hashOperationReturnCode = PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(
      password.cstring,
      -1,
      salt.cstring,
      len(salt).cint,
      iterations.cint,
      digest,
      hashLength,
      outputStartingpoint
    )

  let wasHashSuccessful = hashOperationReturnCode == 1
  doAssert wasHashSuccessful

  result = encode(output)
```

```
name ............................... min time      avg time    std dv   runs
openssl ............................ 0.226 ms      0.230 ms    ±0.009  x1000
python ............................. 0.233 ms      0.244 ms    ±0.031  x1000
```